# Installing software on Solaris

Tags: unix, solaris

I'd like to install several unix utilities (incl. xmlstarlet, wget) on a solaris 10 machine which I don't have root access to (obviously, I have a user account). I'm not that experienced with solaris and am wondering if I can simply get hold of an uber binary for each utility I need and just place this in my home directory? Is this feasible?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

wget is installed by default on Solaris 10 in /usr/sfw/bin/wget.

xmlstarlet requires four libraries that aren't included in Solaris 10 so it's going to be trickier but of course, you can build them and then xmlstarlet from their respective source code.

Have a look there for information about what is needed: http://www.opencsw.org/packages/xmlstarlet

If you really don't want to compile the binaries, there is certainly a way to manually install the files stored on these Solaris packages elsewhere and patch/fix them to make the whole work. I did that already.

Finally, don't underestimate the willingness of the system administrator to help.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the binary doesn't try to do something that requires superuser privileges *and* the binary is compiled for your platform, you should be ok.

Comment: and assuming library dependencies available.otherwise have to hunt libraries.

Comment: Is there any easy way to obtain/construct the uber binary? Looking on blastwave, the xmlstarlet package depends on several other packages which will need to be downloaded and compiled etc. I dont have much experience with compiling/building c libraries and am wondering if I can obtain something 'off the shelf' :)